# Improve Big O notation of algorithm from O(n^2) to something better

Tags: string, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I'm looking to improve an algorithm that I currently have which, whilst it works, currently has the complexity of O(n^2).  I'm looking to reduce that complexity if possible, or improve/change the algorithm itself in order to improve the runtime.

I have a list of strings that each contain multiple words and the end goal is to find "matches" between these strings, sorted based upon a percentage "likeness".

Let's say I have the following strings:

"The End Of The World"
"The Start Of The Journey"
"The End Of Time"
"Time We Left This World Today"

My algorithm performs the following steps:

- Iterate through each string, breaking each string into it's constituent words and re-ordering those words alphabetically (case is insensitive in the whole algorithm).
  (i.e. "The End Of The World" becomes "End Of The The World".  "Time We Left This World Today" becomes "Left This Time Today We World" etc.)
- For business reasons, certain words are stripped from the processed string.  This is usually pronouns and other such words - i.e. a, the etc., so "The End Of The World"  becomes "End Of World".
- We now have a list of strings, broken and reassembled alphabetically from their constituent words with specific non-essential words removed.
- Firstly, I can simply see if there are any exact duplicates in the list.  This is trivial and allows me to identify those strings that are effectively a 100% match.
- Now, however, comes the harder part and the slowest portion of the algorithm.  I have to iterate over the list of strings, comparing each string with every other string in the list (i.e. a nested loop) to determine how many words each string, from the two being compared, have in common.  i.e. When comparing "End Of World" and "End Of Time", there's 66.6% commonality since both strings have two out of three words in common.  When comparing "End Of World" with "Left This Time Today We World" we find there's only one word in common between the two strings (since there's differing numbers of words in each string, the actual percentage in this case is calculated based upon a kind-of average between the two - so approx. 22% commonality).

Ultimately, I'm left with pairs of strings (every possible pairing of all strings in the starting list) and a percentage value of the match between them.  I can then discard all those matches below some threshold and work only with those that are above the threshold.   The threshold is user-defined, and the whole algorithm serves as a way to "filter" a very large set of data, allowing human eyeballs to work with only on those pieces of data that seem closely matched in the first place.

As you can imagine from the nested loop (i.e. the O(n^2)) section of the algorithm, this is very slow and gets considerably slower as the size of input grows.

**Is there any way to improve the Big O of this algorithm or are there any changes to the algorithm producing the same output that will improve the runtime complexity?**

Comment: The first part of the algorithm is on the order of O(n^2) as well if you have N words and N lines to scan over

Comment: No, not without doing something like putting each sentence into a data structure such as a binary tree.  By the way, the trivial words you remove are usually called _stop words_.

Comment: Often (but not always...) in this situation, the rarer the word, the more importance should be assigned to the fact that it happens to be shared by a pair of titles.  In that case, it can help to turn things around by recording, for each word, the set of titles that have that word.  Then for each word (starting with words that appear in the fewest titles), add a weight to each pair of titles having that word (you could store these pairs in a hashtable).  Stop once the title count starts getting too big.

Comment: The way that the problem is framed sounds like a solution that demands O(n^2) complexity at the minimum. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to find all pairs greater than a matching threshold, yes? If so, that requires looking at all pairs which is an O(n^2) operation in and of itself.

Comment: @meat Saying the whole thing is `O(n^2)` doesn't make much sense to me.  It's `O(M*N*N)`, roughly, where `M` is the number of sentences, and `N` the average number of terms in each sentence.  But, as it came out below, the OP already can get this down to `O(M*N*lgN)`.

Comment: If `M` is the number of sentences, examining all pairs of sentences is an `O(M^2)` operation. I missed the fact that `N` in this context was referring to the terms, not sentences.

Comment: Hash each word so when checking between 2 list of strings how many words match, you can compare the hash and if they are equal, you compare the actual words. Also sort strings by amount of words and avoid processing pairs where even if all words match, it would still be below the threshold

Answer (score 1):

There is the extra complication if your pulling the strings around with you in all computations, which makes the last operation not O(M^2) but O(M^2 * sizeof(sentence) * AvgLength(word))

Lets see (concept code)

```
std::vector<std::set<int>> sSets;
sentenceSets.reserve(sentences.size());

for(auto& sentence : sentences) { // O(m)
  std::vector<const char *> words = SplitWord(sentence); // O(n) needs to go through all letters.
  sSet.emplace_back();
  for(auto& word: words) {
    int wordNo = LookUp(word); // table of all words, with entries of 0 for unwanted words. O(log AllWords)
    if (wordNo)
      sSet.back().insert(wordNo); // also removes duplicates. O(Log(#diff words in sentence))
  }
}
```

Total O(m Log(AllWords) avgWordLen) or O(m collisionFactor avgWordLen) if you believe your hash table of all possible words works perfectly.

`LookUp` saves a factor O(letters in word) for all later compares.

```
for(const auto& theSet : sSet) { // O(sSet.size()
  for(const auto& cmpSet : sSet) { // O(sSet.size()
    std::vector<int> intersect;
    std::set_intersection(theSet.begin(), theSet.end(),
                          cmpSet.begin(), cmpSet.end(),
                          std::back_insert<std::vector<int>>(intersect)); // O(set.size())
    StoreRes(theSet, cmpSet, intersect);
  }
}
```

Total here is O(sSet.size()^2*O(set.size()).
Could be optimized to only run O(sSet.size()*sSet.size()/2) as the table is symmetric.

Using the `LookUp` saves a factor O(word size) here.

The std::set might be replaced with some flat_set for faster real world operations.